# How to count the total number of sections within a chapter?

Tags: counters

How can one count the total number of sections *within* each chapter?

I am trying to use the `totcount` package, but it returns the total number of sections of the *last* chapter, not total number of sections of the *current* chapter.

In the following MWE, the desired behaviour would be to report 3 sections for the first Chapter, and 1 section for the second and last chapter.

`totcount` reports only 1 section (the counter value for the last chapter).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{First Chapter}

The total number of sections in this chapter should be 3.

The totcount package reports: \total{section}

\section{First Section}
First text

\section{Second Section}
Second text

\section{Third Section}
Third text

\chapter*{Last Chapter}

The total number of sections in this chapter should be 1.

The totcount package reports: \total{section}

\section{First and only section}
Section text

\end{document}
```

---

How can one count the total number of sections within each chapter?

Note: `totcount` reports 0 sections if using `\section*`, see Sigur's comment.

Comment: `\section*{}` does not increase the counter `section` so it is not counted.

Comment: I see, thank you. I guess, if needed,, one could create and manage his own counter. That answer the second issue, thank you.

Comment: @gsl: `assoccnt` might help

Comment: @christian-hupfer: Thank you, I believe that would be a solution. Would you care to submit a brief answer (perhaps with example) , so that I can accept it?

Comment: @gsl: See below

Comment: @gsl: The newest version is online

Comment: @gsl: I just uploaded a pre-version of a new package named `cntpersec` to CTAN. It provides the means of storing counter values on a per chapter base and displaying the values in advance after two compilation runs have been made. If you send me an email to my address (see my profile page), I'll send you the package files with some preliminary documentation as long it's not fully available on CTAN

Comment: Thank you so much, I have just sent it. I am looking forward to try your new package.

Comment: @gsl: The improved version of the package, renamed to `cntperchap` is now available on CTAN

Comment: Nice,  I can see it there: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cntperchap I am still testing it, everything looks fine. In case I will send separate message with possible notes. Thanks!

Comment: @gsl: The new version 0.2 of `cntperchap` is on CTAN meanwhile

Comment: @christian-hupfer, thank you for letting me know. Since TexLive right now does not update, it is not easy to know about any new changes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Edit** The look-ahead - version of knowing section numbers per chapter in advance is at the very end of this post. It requires two
>   runs of compilation.

This question lead to a new package `cntperchap` which is available in its version 0.2 on CTAN since 2015/9/5

This uses the `assoccnt` package (whose author I accidentally know quite well ;-))

It associates a counter `totalsections` to the `section` counter -- each time the `section` counter is increased, the `totalsections` counter is stepped as well.

However, there is no automatic resetting for `\chapter*` usage. In this case, it can be done automatically by prepending some code to `\chapter` using `\xpretocmd` from `xpatch` package

*Note* The author of `assoccnt` should really incorporate this into his package ;-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{assoccnt}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcounter{totalsections}[chapter] % Does not work with `chapter*`

% Automatically provide for resetting of the section counter each time 
%`\chapter` or `\chapter*` is used -- in this setup this is requested.
\xpretocmd{\chapter}{\setcounter{totalsections}{0}}{}{}


\DeclareAssociatedCounters{section}{totalsections}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{First Chapter}

The total number of sections in this chapter should be 3.



\section{First Section}
First text

\section{Second Section}
Second text

\section{Third Section}
Third text

There \number\value{totalsections} sections in this chapter

\chapter*{Last Chapter}


\section{First and only section}
Section text

There \number\value{totalsections} sections in this chapter


\end{document}
```

**Edit** Some new version, which uses a per chapter count of sections (requires two runs to be successful).

Explanation: Each time a new chapter is used, the accumulated number of sections is written to external file, `\jobname.seccnt`, say `foo.seccnt` for short. This file is read again at the next latex compile run and the values are stored to a `etoolbox` list. The macro `\GetTotalSectionCounter` will advance through this list until it's at the right position and will then print out the number of sections in this chapter, even ahead.  (The macro should be expandable, I think this is the case)

At the moment, it's necessary to manually remove the `foo.seccnt` file if there have been changes to number of chapters/sections.

I'll try to get around this drawback.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{assoccnt}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{pgffor} % Only for quick usage of a lot of sections, demo only

\newwrite\seccountfile%

\newread\seccountinfile%

\listgadd{\seccountlist}{}% Initialize an empty list


\newcounter{currentchapter}
\newcounter{totalsections}
\newcounter{togglecounter}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{section}{totalsections}


\newcommand{\getsectioncountnumbers}{%
  \setcounter{togglecounter}{0}%  
  \whiledo {\value{togglecounter} < 1}{%
    \read\seccountinfile to \gandalf%
    \ifeof\seccountinfile%
    \stepcounter{togglecounter}%
    \else%
    \listxadd{\seccountlist}{\gandalf}%
    \fi%
  }%
}


\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \stepcounter{currentchapter}%
  \immediate\write\seccountfile{%
    \number\value{totalsections}%
  }%
  \setcounter{totalsections}{0}
}{}{}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{tempcount@a}
\newcommand{\@getsectiontotalcounter}[1]{%
  \setcounter{tempcount@a}{0}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{#1}}{\value{tempcount@a}}{%
      ##1\listbreak%
    }{%
      \stepcounter{tempcount@a}%
    }%  
  }%    
  \dolistloop{\seccountlist}%
}   


\newcommand{\GetSectionTotalCounter}[1][currentchapter]{%
  \ifdef{\seccountlist}{%
    \@getsectiontotalcounter{#1}%
    }{}%
}

\makeatother


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \IfFileExists{\jobname.seccnt}{%
    % Open for reading
    \immediate\openin\seccountinfile=\jobname.seccnt%
    \getsectioncountnumbers%
  }{%
    % Open for writing
    \immediate\openout\seccountfile=\jobname.seccnt%
  }%
}



\AtEndDocument{% 
  \immediate\write\seccountfile{%
    \number\value{totalsections}%
  }%
  \immediate\closeout\seccountfile%
}




\begin{document}

\chapter*{First}
This chapter will have \GetSectionTotalCounter sections
\section{First}
\section{Second}

\chapter*{Second}
This chapter will have \GetSectionTotalCounter sections
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\section{Third}
\section{Fourth}


% Now a really large chapter
\chapter*{Third}
This chapter will have \GetSectionTotalCounter sections

\foreach \x in {1,...,100} {%
\section{\x}
}

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit** This is the version without explicit deleting the `foo.seccnt` file

I used the `addtocontents` approach to let `LaTeX` write the section numbers to a separate file just as it is done with the `toc` related stuff. The `foo.seccnt` is then treated as a faked toc, read in before (and the values temporarily stored) rewritten in the run.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{assoccnt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\listgadd{\seccountlist}{}% Initialize an empty list

\newcounter{currentchapter}
\newcounter{totalsections}
\newcounter{togglecounter}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{section}{totalsections}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getsectioncountnumbers}{%
  \setcounter{togglecounter}{0}%  
  \whiledo {\value{togglecounter} < 1}{%
    \read\tf@seccnt to \seccountnumberfromfile%
    \ifeof\tf@seccnt
    \stepcounter{togglecounter}%
    \else%
    \listxadd{\seccountlist}{\seccountnumberfromfile}%
    \fi%
  }%
}


\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \stepcounter{currentchapter}%
  \addtocontents{seccnt}{%
    \number\value{totalsections}%
  }%
  \setcounter{totalsections}{0}
}{}{}

\newcounter{tempcount@a}
\newcommand{\@getsectiontotalcounter}[1]{%
  \setcounter{tempcount@a}{0}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{#1}}{\value{tempcount@a}}{%
      ##1\listbreak%
    }{%
      \stepcounter{tempcount@a}%
    }%  
  }%    
  \dolistloop{\seccountlist}%
}   

\newcommand{\GetSectionTotalCounter}[1][currentchapter]{%
  \ifdef{\seccountlist}{%
    \@getsectiontotalcounter{#1}%
  }{}%
}

% This is a modified version from \@starttoc, being defined latex.ltx
\def\@startfaketoc#1{%
  \begingroup
  % Generate the file handle first
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname%
  \makeatletter
  % Read first before deleting it
  \ifcsdef{tf@#1}{%
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.#1}{%
    \immediate\openin\csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \getsectioncountnumbers%
    }{}
  }{%
    \typeout{No section count numbers so far}
  }%
  \if@filesw
  % Write only if not `\nofiles` is specified
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup%
}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@startfaketoc{seccnt}
}



\AtEndDocument{%
  % Write the last section count to the file
  \addtocontents{seccnt}{%
    \number\value{totalsections}%
  }%
}
\makeatother




\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{First}
This chapter will have \GetSectionTotalCounter sections
\section{First}
\section{Second}

\chapter*{Second}
This chapter will have \GetSectionTotalCounter sections
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\section{Third}
\section{Fourth}



% Now a really large chapter
\chapter*{Third}
This chapter will have \GetSectionTotalCounter sections

\foreach \x in {1,...,100} {%
\section{\x}
}

\chapter{Fourth}
This chapter will have \GetSectionTotalCounter sections

\section{A single section}


\end{document}
```

**Edit** The OP gsl noted some error in this code. I could track it down to the fact that `\@startfaketoc` tries to read in the external `foo.seccnt` file in the first run already. This fails of course, since there is no such file if it was deleted or the documentat is compiled for the very first time.

Comment: @gsl: Yes, it has some advantages, but it has to be used with care! It's no swiss-knife ;-) Happy texing

Comment: If one needs to know the value of `totalsections` at any place withing a chapter, like for example at the beginning, like in the MWE, it seems that system is not working. Just move the line `There are \number\value{totalsections} sections in this chapter` right after `\chapter` to see what I mean, or see this MWE: http://paste.lisp.org/display/147711

Comment: @gls: Yes, I see the point. I will think about it. It will probably need more than one run to achieve since `assoccnt` can't ahead how many sections there will be per chapter in advance.

Comment: @gls: How many chapters do you intend to use in your document? I try to use a new setup

Comment: It is a manual with about 100 chapters (900 pages long). Each chapter has from 1 to about 10 sections. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @gsl: 100 chapters? :D :D

Comment: It would be fine to have multiple passes (I do not think there is any other way). That book has many short chapters, still it would be nice for a way to deal with any kind of counters. I have been searching for this for days, I do not think it is available yet, at least as package.

Comment: @gsl: I am still working on it, but the first version will be a hack, nothing nice

Comment: @gsl: See the update at the lower half of my answer. It's not very nice so far

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23348/discussion-between-gsl-and-christian-hupfer).

Comment: I am not sure how one can be notified of chat new comments. Anyway, Thank you for the new version!