# Count total marks and questions

Tags: macros, counters, exam

I'm trying to calculate the total number of questions and total marks based on an exam paper I'm currently writing.

My MEW:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{exam}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 1}
This section has 3 questions from Question 1-3 with a total marks of 3.

\begin{questions}

\question[1] Q1

\question[1] Q2

\question[1] Q3

\section*{Section 2}
\uplevel{This section has 3 questions from Question 4-6 with a total marks of 5}

\question[]
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] Q4 Part a. 
    \part[1] Q4 Part b.
\end{parts}

\question[]
\begin{parts}
    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart[1]
        \subpart[1]
    \end{subparts}
\end{parts}

\question[1]
Q6

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to make the following lines dyanmic.

`This section has 3 questions from Question 1-3 with a total marks of 3.` %Section 1

`This section has 3 questions from Question 4-6 with a total marks of 5` % Section 2

So that as my paper changes in terms of questions and marks, the above lines will change reflecting the paper.

I've tried to use counters,and changed each question to `aquestion` and `bquestion` but they don't give me the desired results I want.

```
\newtotcounter{a} 
\setcounter{a}{0}
\newcommand{\aquestion}[0]{\stepcounter{a}\question}

\newtotcounter{b} 
\setcounter{b}{0}
\newcommand{\bquestion}[0]{\stepcounter{b}\question}
```

Further note*

I've also used `\begingradinginrange{}` `\numqinrange` but it doesn't give me the desired results of:

a) How many questions there are?
b) What are the question numbers i.e 1-3 or 4-6 etc
c) Total marks for those sections.

Comment: So you want the number to be updated based on the number of `\question` items follow it and before the next `\section`?

Comment: @user202729,  yes i want the  number of questions to be updated based on the sections.

Comment: Somewhat similar to [sectioning - How to count the total number of subsections within a section? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308468/how-to-count-the-total-number-of-subsections-within-a-section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer I need.

`This section has \numqinrange{myrange} questions from Question \firstqinrange{myrange}-\lastqinrange{myrange} with a total marks of \pointsinrange{myrange}`

As long as I place the `\begingradinginrange{myrange}` and `\endgradinginrange{myrange}` I was able to make it dynamic.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 1}
This section has \numqinrange{myrange} questions from Question \firstqinrange{myrange}-\lastqinrange{myrange} with a total marks of \pointsinrange{myrange}

\begin{questions}
    
\begingradingrange{myrange}

\question[1] Q1

\question[1] Q2

\question[1] Q3
\endgradingrange{myrange}

\section*{Section 2}
\uplevel{This section has \numqinrange{myrange1} questions from Question \firstqinrange{myrange1}-\lastqinrange{myrange1} with a total marks of \pointsinrange{myrange1}}

\begingradingrange{myrange1}
\question[]
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] Q4 Part a. 
    \part[1] Q4 Part b.
\end{parts}

\question[]
\begin{parts}
    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart[1]
        \subpart[1]
    \end{subparts}
\end{parts}

\endgradingrange{myrange1}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fine :) // Can you please include the required package(s) in your post, via the Edit-button? This way more people can re-use your findings later. Thanks

Comment: @MS-SPO, you can test it out and see if it work from your end :). I'm learning quiet a lot from this forum. I still have 1 problem.